# Within-person centering the outcome variable?

Tags: repeated-measures, centering, dependent-variable

What do you think of within-person centering the outcome variable? If my research questions is clearly about within-person effects (in a longitudinal multilevel model), can I just use the centered version as the outcome/dependent variable?